# Odd regex maches and different from tester

Tags: c++, regex

I've following regex to match HTTP headers and body on a input string:

`([^()<>@,;:\\\"/\\[\\]?={}\\s\\t]+):(?:[\\s\\t]+)?(.+)\\r\\n(?:\\r\\n([\\s\\S]+))?`

Parentheses bellow show expected matches:

```
(Header-Name): (Its_value)
(Im-a-header): (Im_a_value)

(Anything here,
commonly HTML code...
...)
```

It works fine in Regex101.com using PCRE, Python or JavaScript flavors, but when I test it in C++ using `regex_search`, only first header is matched and no more, even body. Using Perl flavor from `boost::regex` produces even more strange output.

Test code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        const std::string data("Name: value\r\nFoo: bar\r\n\r\nanything\r\nhere");
        std::regex pattern("([^()<>@,;:\\\"/\\[\\]?={}\\s\\t]+):(?:[\\s\\t]+)?(.+)\\r\\n(?:\\r\\n([\\s\\S]+))?");
        std::smatch result;

        std::regex_search(data, result, pattern);

        for(const auto &match : result)
                std::cout << match << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Name: value

Name
value
```

Output changing from `std` to `boost` (and automatically to Perl flavor):

```
Name: value
Foo: bar

anything here

Name
value
Foo: bar

anything here
```

Obs.: I used `boost` only to test resulting output. I don't want any Perl specific solution.

I would like to get an output similar to the following with such code:

```
Name
value
Foo
bar
anything
here
```

Can somebody understand what is the problem and help me with this, please?

Comment: Which Compiler and version exactly? With GCC prior 4.9 regex was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are several issues.

1. You need to run `regex_search` several times to obtain several matches each havinf capturing groups.
2. Since you will need to modify the input string, you will need to declare it as not a constant.
3. The regex itself places `anything\r\nhere` into group 3, and you should check if it is filled out before trying to print/obtain it.

Here is a fixed version:

```
string data("Name: value\r\nFoo: bar\r\n\r\nanything\r\nhere");
std::regex pattern("([^()<>@,;:\\\\\"/\\[\\]?={}\\s]+):\\s*(.+)\r\n(?:\r\n([\\s\\S]+))?");
std::smatch result;

while (regex_search(data, result, pattern)) {
    std::cout << result[1] << "\n" << result[2] << std::endl;
    if (result[3].str().size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << result[3] << std::endl;
    }
    data = result.suffix().str();
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/76pxwG). Output:

```
Name
value
Foo
bar
anything
here
```

Comment: I might be wrong assuming that ``\\\"`` matches ``\`` and `"`. If that is not the case, the regex should be `pattern("([^()<>@,;:\"/\\[\\]?={}\\s]+):\\s+?(.+)\r\n(?:\r\n([\\s\\S]+))?")`. Note that I removed the `\t` from the first character class as it is already matched by `\s`, and also optimized escaping a bit. Also, `(?:[\\s\\t]+)?` = `\\s*`. Note that you need to add a `?` quantifier after `\r` to support both Unix and Windows newline style, or to support all major OSes: `(?:\r\n|\n|\r)`.

Comment: Thanks, @stribizhev. I read that on C++ reference, but forgot it when writing the code. You're right, `\\\"` matches `\` and `"`. Why `\s` and `\S` needs double escape (`\\s` and `\\S`) whereas `\r` and `\n` doesn't?

Comment: Linebreaks can be passed to the regex engine as literals, there is no difference from the point of view of end result. Shorthand character classes must be escaped for the regex engine, with double backslash.